# access member without getter setter in c++

Tags: c++, reference, private, accessor

I am clusmy at using English. Hope you can uderstand.

How can we access private member wihtout getter ? I can't understand it.

When we learned about C++ private, public, protected, private member or function can be accessed at class scope.

```cpp
class TestClass {
public:
   TestClass() {
     testMem = 10;
   }

   void testFunction() {
     cout << testMem << endl;
   }
private:
   int testMem;
}
```

but, i'm really confused when i saw this code.

```cpp
class B {
public:
    B() {
          testNumber = 10;
        }

        void printMember() {
          cout << testNumber << endl;
        }

private:
    int testNumber;
}

class Money {
public:
    Money();
        bool operator < (Money& amount, B& b) const {
           // this code doesn't make any error
           // why same type member can access their private member directly without getter and setter?
           amount.cents = 10;
           amount.dollors = 10;

           // this Code make a error
           // b.testNumber = 10;

           // below
           // compare code
        } 

private:
    int dollars;
    int cents;
};
```

i'm really confused.. why Money& amount parameter can access their private member without getter and setter ? But B class can't access their private member without getter. how..? why..?

Comment: Private members are designed so that methods outside of the class can't access them.  Privacy helps support concepts like *loose coupling*, *data hiding* and *encapsulation*.  If you **need** to access private members, from methods outside of the class, I recommend reviewing your design.

Comment: this code is jsut for test ! umm how same type parameter can access their member directly without getter?

Answer (score 0):

Line 25: b.testNumber = 10;

This code generates an error because the Money class is trying to directly access the private data member of a different class.

Private data members can only be accessed by the class itself. You could fix this issue by making a function in B to change the data member and then call that function to change it.

An example:

```
class B {
public:
    B() {
          testNumber = 10;
        }

        void changeMember(int newData)
        {
            testNumber = newData;
        }

        void printMember() {
          cout << testNumber << endl;
        }

private:
    int testNumber;
}

class Money {
    friend class B;
public:
    Money();
        bool operator < (Money& amount, B& b) const {
           // this code doesn't make any error
           amount.cents = 10;
           amount.dollars = 10;

           // this Code make a error
           b.changeMember(10);

           // below
           // compare code
        } 

private:
    int dollars;
    int cents;
};
```

Comment: so i annotated some comment at that line. (this code make an error.) what i really want to know is that how same class type parameter can access their private member directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, I think you asking why the line:
        bool operator < (Money& amount, B& b) const {
does not generate an error but the other line does? It is because you are inside the Money class so you are allowed to directly access private data members of that class. The line:
    b.testNumber = 10;
generates an error because you are accessing the data member of a different class.

Comment: so you mean that Money type parameter can access their private member because operator < function is in Money class ? and B class instance can't access their private member because it is B type instance?